# Why am I getting "Android resource linking failed" in my styles.xml file (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Hi I'm working in Android Studio and trying to create a background for my splash screen that uses my 'rideshare_splash' image as the background as in the tutorial I've been following at this timestamp (https://youtu.be/144TuYxEu2M?t=572) but when I go to build I get an error saying 'Android resource linking failed'.

I've looked at similarly titled threads on here but the most relevant ones suggested using *attr name* instead which didn't work as it was outdated, then I tried the suggestion of having *android:colorPrimary* but that didn't help either so I thought I'd try asking my own question.

**styles.xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Error message (copy & pasted from build console)**

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
    Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\mecha\AndroidStudioProjects\FYP_RideShareApp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimary (aka codebymech.fyprideshareapp:color/colorPrimary) not found.
         
     C:\Users\mecha\AndroidStudioProjects\FYP_RideShareApp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource color/colorPrimaryDark (aka codebymech.fyprideshareapp:color/colorPrimaryDark) not found.
         
     C:\Users\mecha\AndroidStudioProjects\FYP_RideShareApp\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:4:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource color/colorAccent (aka codebymech.fyprideshareapp:color/colorAccent) not found.
```

**Extra information**

My idea is that there's something wrong with how the tutorial has uses @color/coolorPrimary (as well as colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent) or maybe something about this in the tutorial is outdated as it is a couple months old?

*Also a side note: when I opened Android Studio there was no styles.xml only colors, strings and themes .xml files so I had to add my own styles.xml file to follow as the tutorial was doing so maybe that has had an effect?*

Comment: Have you defined these colors (colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent) in colors.xml ?. If not then add it

Comment: I didn't know I had to do that, I'm still new to Android Studio but thank you very much for that, I just made the adjustments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your colors.xml file does not containg these colors(colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and colorAccent) You have to define these colors in your color.xml file.

Comment: Still having the same issue. do you have any other suggestions ?